# Why is the argument passed to __getattribute__ not recognized?

Tags: python-3.x, function, getattribute

A very basic question.

I have some dummy class:

```
class SomeClass:
    """ just a docstring"""

    a = 5
```

dir(SomeClass), returns the following attributes associated with this class:

```
>>> dir(SomeClass)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__form
at__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_s
ubclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__',
 '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclas
shook__', '__weakref__', 'a']
>>>
```

I noticed that if I make a call to SomeClass.__getattribute__, even if I pass an argument to it (which it says it requires), **the error message says I am not passing any argument.**

```
>>> SomeClass.__getattribute__('a')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: expected 1 arguments, got 0
>>>
```

Note - *it's not that I have a use-case for wanting to call __getattribute__ in this way.*  (In fact seems incorrect to do so, that I'd want to call it on an instance of SomeClass instead, which DOES work).  **I'm just curious about the behavior of __getattribute__: why does the error message say it got 0 arguments, when I am actually passing an argument to it?**  I'm not disputing that my usage is incorrect - just, why doesn't __getattribute__ recognize that it was passed an argument?

I did notice that __getattribute__ is listed as a 'slotwrapper'.  Does this have to do with it?  I'm having a hard time figuring out what is the real difference between calling a slotwrapper and calling a function.  Does this slotwrapper toss out the argument I have passed it, because of the way I've called it?

```
>>> SomeClass.__getattribute__
<slot wrapper '__getattribute__' of 'object' objects>
>>>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `__getattribute__` that you're calling is a method. It expects *two* arguments. The first argument is `self`, which will usually be an instance of `SomeClass` (and usually gets provided automatically when you call via an instance: `instance.__getattribute__`). The second argument is the name of an attribute to look up.

When you call `SomeClass.__getattribute__("a")`, you're passing `"a"` as `self`. That's not a very useful thing to do. If you provided a second argument too, it might even work (since `SomeClass.__getattribute__` is inherited from `object`, as is `str.__getattribute__`). It will be looking up attributes on the string you pass in though, not on anything related to `SomeClass`.

The only odd behavior is that it says got zero arguments (and expected one), rather than the saying that it got one argument and expected two. *That* part of the issue might be a (minor) bug.

Comment: Thanks so much for explaining.  I was very confused by the error message itself.  It's a similar issue with \__setattr\__, if I pass it two arguments when calling this (incorrect) way, the error message says it expects 2 arguments but only received 1.  (Seems that it should really be expecting 3 arguments though - the instance, the name of the attribute you want to set, and the value to set it to).

Comment: I suspect the bogus error messages are because those are methods written in C (which you're inheriting from `object`). Builtin methods are a bit weird. If you wrote your own method in Python, it would give an appropriate error message if call it incorrectly.

Answer (score 2):

You can also try `getattr(SomeClass, "a")`. This worked for me in a similar case.